# Why does APL's ⊥-decode need the extra number in the radix vector?

Tags: decode, apl

APL has a primitive function that is used to "decode" other number bases. On the left hand side of the function, you put the place value associated for each digit in the other number base. On the right hand side you put a vector of the digits you are interested in.

For example:

```
    2 2 2 2 ⊥ 0 1 0 1   ⍝ (What you type in) Convert 0101 form base 2 into base 10
5                       ⍝ (What the interpreter computes)
```

However, the leftmost 2 in the radix vector is never used in any decode computation. For example,

```
      ¯48 2 2 2 ⊥ 0 1 0 1 ⍝ We can replace the leftmost radix digit with a random number
5                         ⍝ Same answer as before

      ¯48 2 2 2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1 ⍝ Just to prove that the leftmost decode digit is unused
15                        ⍝ Correct decode of 1111

      65 2 2 2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1  ⍝ Try another random number for testing
15                        ⍝ Again, the correct answer is output
```

So if the leftmost digit is never used, why on Earth does APL require it? (Specifically, APL requires both the radix vector and input vector to have the same length) Is there some use for the decode function that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Perhaps it's used to validate that the leftmost value digit is in range?

Comment: Hmm, good thought. However, the interpreter doesn't seem to complain:
`2 2 2 2 ⊥ 44 1 1 1` gives `359`

Answer (score 2):

Your statement

> Specifically, APL requires both...to have the same length

is only partially right. To quote from the [Dyalog APL Manual](http://help.dyalog.com/15.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Encode.htm):

> X and Y are conformable if the length of the last axis of X is the same as the length of the first axis of Y.  A scalar or 1-element vector is extended to a vector of the required length.  If the last axis of X or the first axis of Y has a length of 1, the array is extended along that axis to conform with the other argument.

So, that means that `2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1`is sufficient to compute `15`.

I found a great explanation [here](http://www.sigapl.org/encode.php), but as that page has font-problems, I'll reproduce it with the proper font:

From B, the radix vector in the statement `Q←B⊥R`, we compute a weighting vector, `W`, as the first step of the evaluation. Using a specific example: `0 3 12 ⊥ 4 2 7` (converting yards, feet and inches to inches), compute a weighting vector from `B` as follows:

```
inches per yard: 3⊥12 or 36 
inches per foot: 12
inches per inch: 1
```

The weighting vector is `36 12 1`. In APL, the process for evaluation of the weighting vector can be written:

```
      N←⍴B               ⍝ Length of B
      W←N⍴0              ⍝ Give W the proper shape
      W[1]←×/1↓B         ⍝ Product of all but the first element  of B
      W[2]←×/2↓B         ⍝ Product of all but the first 2 elements  of B  etc.
         .               ⍝ etc.
         .
         .
      W[N-1]←×/(N-1)↓B   ⍝ Next to last element of W is last  element of B
      W[N]←1             ⍝ Last element of W is always I
```

Note that the first element of B was not used. To complete the evaluation of encode, take the sum of W times R:

```
      Q←+/W×R
```

This result is `B⊥R`. For our specific example:

```
      36 12 1 ⊥ 4 2 7
144 24 7

      144 + 24 + 7
175
      0 3 12 ⊥ 4 2 7
175
```

Comment: "Note that the first element of B was not used". Exactly my point; if it is never used, why must it be there? Is it because APL needs it for memory alignment or something like that?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have an authoritive answer on that, but I guess...
* the left argument can be used to perform the inverse operation, and _then_ the first element makes sense   * probably the implementors like the symmetry of the args...

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the arguments to ⊥ need to be conformable.

```
2 2 2 2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1       ⍝ ok
2 2 2 2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1 1     ⍝ length error
      2 ⊥ 1 1 1 1       ⍝ scalar extension of the left argument
2 2 2 2 ⊥ 1             ⍝ scalar extension of the right argument
```

Arguments to ⊥ extend to higher order arrays, and as in inner product, the last dimension of the left argument must match the first dimension of the right.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything to add to MBaas' excellent answer, but I'll share a bug in in APL2 on IBM mainframe regarding `⊥`.

Since it might of interest to others, I put it in a separate question: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138313/interesting-bug-in-apl2-on-ibm-mainframe-regarding-%E2%8A%A5/41138314#41138314).